# Ошибка: "ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Возвратные типы переменных Result Set или запроса не совпадают" с BULK COLLECT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, коллекции

Eсть такая таблица, в которой только пара записей (в будущем их будет больше):

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (ID, VALUE) AS
    SELECT 8,   265.7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,   559.6 FROM DUAL;
```

Создаю к ней соответствующие типы данных:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HASHMAP_NUM_TYPE_OBJ AS OBJECT (
    ID                 NUMBER,
    VALUE              NUMBER(10,1))
/    
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HASHMAP_NUM_TYPE IS TABLE OF HASHMAP_NUM_TYPE_OBJ
/
```

И пытаюсь получить записи, используя `BULK COLLECT`:

```
DECLARE 
    stats_by_measure HASHMAP_NUM_TYPE;
    cursor_1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN 
    OPEN cursor_1 FOR
        SELECT ID, VALUE
        FROM MYTABLE;

    FETCH cursor_1 BULK COLLECT INTO stats_by_measure;
    CLOSE cursor_1;
END;
/
```

> Error report -
> ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Возвратные типы переменных Result Set или запроса не совпадают
> ORA-06512: на  line 9

Почему получаю эту ошибку? Что я делаю не так?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle PL/SQL 6504 with BULK COLLECT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48823498) от участника [@serkelion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5914510/serkelion)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48823498

Answer (score 3):

Причина ошибки - PL/SQL может поместить записи результата запроса в переменную с типом `ROWTTYPE`, но он не может поместить этот же результат в переменную с объектным типом данных, так как необходим конструктор, он не будет вызван неявно:

```
declare 
    obj hashmap_num_type_obj;
    rec my_table%rowtype;
begin 
    select 1, 2 into rec from dual;
    --select 1, 2 into obj from dual; --ORA-00947: не хватает значений для данных
                         --так нельзя --^^^^
    select hashmap_num_type_obj (1, 2) into obj from dual;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Простое и эффективное решение - преобразовать сет результата в коллекцию с [CAST (MULTISET query)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75), и вернуть её простым `INTO collection variable`. И для коллекци, и для её элементов, конструкторы будут вызваны неявно. Воспроизводимый пример:

```
rc refcursor
declare 
    rs hashmap_num_type;
begin 
    select cast (
        multiset (select * from my_table) as hashmap_num_type) into rs 
    from dual;
    open :rc for select * from table (rs);
end;
/
    THE_ID  THE_VALUE
---------- ----------
         8      265,7
         7      559,6
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение с `BULK COLLECT` может оказаться более эффективным, если в результате запроса получится большой набор данных для коллекции. Решением в примере ниже будет явный вызов конструктора. С клаузой `LIMIT` можно обработать большой результат запроса по частям:

```
declare 
    cursor c is 
        select hashmap_num_type_obj (id, value) 
        from mytable; 
    rs hashmap_num_type;
begin 
    open c;
    loop fetch c bulk collect into rs limit 10000;
        exit when rs.count = 0;
        for i in 1..rs.count loop 
            dbms_output.put_line ('result('||i||') id='||rs(i).id||' value='||rs(i).value); 
        end loop;    
    end loop; 
end;
/ 
result(1) id=8 value=265,7
result(2) id=7 value=559,6
```

Если объектный тип данных не предпололается использовать в SQL контексте, то простым решением будет - создать коллекцию с элементами типа `ROWSET` самого курсора:

```
declare 
    cursor c is 
        select id, value 
        from mytable;
    type resultSet is table of c%rowtype;    
    rs resultSet;
begin 
    open c;
    loop fetch c bulk collect into rs limit 10000;
        exit when rs.count = 0;
        for i in 1..rs.count loop 
            dbms_output.put_line ('result('||i||') id='||rs(i).id||' value='||rs(i).value); 
        end loop;    
    end loop; 
end;
/
result(1) id=8 value=265,7
result(2) id=7 value=559,6
```

---

PS Обратите внимание, условие выхода из цикла не `NOTFOUND` как обычно принято, это частый источник ошибки - коллекция в этом случае может содержать последние выбранные элементы.